# How to make accurate capacitance measurements using LCR meter IET/QuadTech 7600 Plus Precision?

Tags: measurement, capacitance

Some students in my department are studying a flat capacitor comb printed on a Volterra PCB. The sample we measured had 19 fingers and a spacing of approximately 216 µm. I need help guiding them how to make accurate measurements using an IET/QuadTech 7600 Plus Precision LCR meter. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to run 4 shielded coax wires to a Kelvin connection at the DUT and to measure under open/short conditions first to zero the meter. Your LCR meter should have force and sense connections (maybe called current and potential) for both high and low.

Here, for example, is a measurement of a "gimmick" twisted PE wire capacitor which yields a stable 0.8pF reading on an inexpensive meter after calibration. Each side of each clip runs to a separate piece of coaxial cable (4 in total) which run back to BNC connectors on the meter.

[image]

Perhaps you could make a PCB with similar geometry open and shorts as well as the capacitor to be tested. Of the two tests, 'open' (zero pF) is more important. You can also perform a double check by connecting a commercial capacitor such as an NP0 10pF +/-1% part, which is quite inexpensive and likely tighter in tolerance than you  need.